# Unable to enter into Apache Karaf docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops, apache-karaf

I have built the Dockerfile with base image apache karaf, but Unable to enter into Apache Karaf docker container

```
[root@HNHC9F2 docker_file]# docker exec -it b8586730289b /opt/karaf/bin/karaf
```

> karaf: There is a Root instance already running with name root and pid 132. If you know what you are doing and want to force the run anyway, export CHECK_ROOT_INSTANCE_RUNNING=false and re run the command.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests you need export the env variable CHECK_ROOT_INSTANCE_RUNNING:

```
docker exec -it b8586730289b bash
export CHECK_ROOT_INSTANCE_RUNNING=false
exit
```

---

```
docker exec -it b8586730289b /opt/karaf/bin/karaf
```

**Update**:

If all you want is to get a shell inside container then below is all that is needed:

```
docker exec -it b8586730289b bash
```

Comment: docker exec -it b8586730289b bash 

works, Its allowing me to go inside the container

Answer (score 1):

To access karaf shell directly you can use following command

```
docker exec -it b8586730289b /opt/apache/karaf/bin/client
```